# numpy set value with indexes?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy like this:

```
arr = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=np.int)
```

then I have a index list:

```
idxs = [1, 4, 7]
```

What I want to do is:

```
for index in idxs:
    arr[index, idxs] = 1
```

I want to know that do I have any better way to do this?
Here, my `better way` means something like `arr[idxs, idxs] = 1`(I know this is wrong), at least, without for loop.

Comment: `arr[np.ix_(idxs,idxs)]=1`

Answer (score 0):

```py
xs = np.zeros((10,10))
idx = np.array([1,4,7])


xs[idx[None].T,idx]=1
# or like some suggested in the comments,which is actually better

xs[np.ix_(idx,idx)]=1
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question.